# How to get loaned money back to US

Tags: india, loans

I had loaned about 150 K money to a relative to purchase a house in India over a period of 8 years. The house never materialized due to some conflicts. My relative is returning the money back with approximately interest 10%, since the amount is big (up to 200K) how do I get it back. What is the way for them to return the money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to pay tax on the 10% gain.

Was this money loaned from your NRE account? Is there paperwork to show that there was this loan given? If yes then it would be easy to get this back into NRE account. Once in NRE account you can move this back to US without any issue.

If not, then you can get this into NRO account. From NRO account you would need to consult a CA to do some paperwork [essentially certifying that you have paid all taxes due] so that funds can be remitted outside.

Edit:
Looks like you have completed all formalities. A credit to NRE Account can only happen from funds outside of India. However a credit from India into NRE account can happen under some circumstances, like Loan give and received back.

You would need a CA in India to help you complete the formalities. The tax is due in India as this was due to gain in India. As you are US resident for tax purposes, and US taxes global income, this is taxable in US as well. You can claim relief in US to the extent of taxes paid in India. India and US have DTAA.

Comment: I sent it to my NRE account and wrote checks. Some I wire transferred by Remit2India or Xoom. I have the details of all the checks issued.  I also have a affidavit signed by this person about the loan. Do I need to consult a CA in US or in India ? The 10% is to be paid in India or in US ?